# Opening SSRS 2005 reports in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

We have some reports created in SQL Server 2005. But Recently we converted them into 2008. But now we are not able to open the same report project in 2008. It is showing an error like this :

> E://Projects/...Reporting.rptproj cannot be opened because its project
>   type (.rptproj) is not supported by this version of the application.
>   To open it, please use a version that supports this type of projects.

We have SQL Server 2008 with SP1 is installed. we are trying to open the reports using SQL Server 2008 Business Intelligence Development Studio.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/9a7a78a0-bf5c-458a-9cb0-bc82004501f7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new project and import the .rdl files. You may also need to import the data source files to get them to connect to the dbs.